# Reading a file with unproperly marked dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, formatting

I have a file with a list of dictionaries, most of them being unproperly marked with quotations marks. An example is the following:

```
{game:Available,player:Available,location:"Chelsea, London, England",time:Available}
{"game":"Available","player":"Available","location":"Chelsea, London, England","time":"Available","date":"Available"}
```

As you can see, the keys can also differ from a dictionary to another.

I tried to read that with the json module, or the DictReader of the csv module, but each time I have difficulties due to the "" always present in the location value, but not always for the other keys or values. Up until this point I see two possibilities:

1. Replacing the "," by ";" in the location value, and getting rid of all the quotes.
2. Adding quotes for every value and key, except the location one.

PS: My final point being to be able to format all these dictionaries to create a SQL table with the columns being the union of all the dictionaries, and each row being one of my dictionary, with blank when there are missing values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very complete code, I think.

First I created the following file:

```
{surprise : "perturbating at start  ", game:Available Universal Dices Game,
    player:FTROE875574,location
:"Lakeview School, Kingsmere Boulevard, Saskatoon, Saskatchewan , Canada",time:15h18}

{"game":"Available","   player":"LOI4531",
"location":  "Perth, Australia","time":"08h13","date":"Available"}

{"game":Available,player:PLLI874,location:"Chelsea, London, England",time:20h35}

{special:"midnight happening",game:"Available","player":YTR44,
"location":"Paris, France","time":"02h24"
,
"date":"Available"}

{game:Available,surprise:"  hretyuuhuhu  ",player:FT875,location
:,"time":11h22}

{"game":"Available","player":"LOI4531","location":
"Damas,Syria","time":"unavailable","date":"Available"}

{"surprise   " : GARAMANANATALA Tower ,  game:Available Dices,player  :
  PuLuLu874,location:"  Westminster, London, England  ",time:20h01}

{"game":"Available",special:"overnight",   "player":YTR44,"location":
"Madrid, Spain"    ,     "time":
"12h33",
date:"Available"
}
```

.

.

Then the following code treats the content of the file in two phases:

- first, running through the content, all the intervening keys in all the dictionaries are collected
- a dictionary **posis** is deducted, that gives for each key the place that its corresponding value must occupy in a row
- secondly, thanks to another run through the file, the rows are build one after the other and collected in a list **rows**

By the way, note that the condition on the value associated with key **location** or **"location"** is respected.

.

```
import re

dicreg = re.compile('(?<=\{)[^}]*}')

kvregx = re.compile('[ \r\n]*'
                    '(" *)?((location)|[^:]+?)(?(1) *")'
                    '[ \r\n]*'
                    ':'
                    '[ \r\n]*'
                    '(?(3)|(" *)?)([^:]*?)(?(4) *")'
                    '[ \r\n]*(?:,(?=[^,]+?:)|\})')


checking_dict = {}
checking_list = []

filename = 'zzz.txt'

with open(filename) as f:

    ######## First part: to gather all the keys in all the dictionaries

    prec,chunk = '','go'
    ecr = []
    while chunk:
        chunk = f.read(120)
        ss = ''.join((prec,chunk))
        ecr.append('\n\n------------------------------------------------------------\nss   == %r' %ss)
        mat_dic = None
        for mat_dic in dicreg.finditer(ss):
            ecr.append('\nmmmmmmm dictionary found in ss mmmmmmmmmmmmmm')
            for mat_kv in kvregx.finditer(mat_dic.group()):
                k,v = mat_kv.group(2,5)
                ecr.append('%s  :  %s' % (k,v))
                if k in checking_list:
                    checking_dict[k] += 1
                else:
                    checking_list.append(k)
                    checking_dict[k] = 1
        if mat_dic:
            prec = ss[mat_dic.end():]
        else:
            prec += chunk

    print '\n'.join(ecr)
    print '\n\n\nchecking_dict == %s\n\nchecking_list        == %s' %(checking_dict,checking_list)

    ######## The keys are sorted in order that the less frequent ones are at the end
    checking_list.sort(key=lambda k: checking_dict[k], reverse=True)
    posis = dict((k,i) for i,k in enumerate(checking_list))
    print '\nchecking_list sorted == %s\n\nposis == %s' % (checking_list,posis)



    ######## Now, the file is read again to build a list of rows 

    f.seek(0,0)  # the file's pointer is move backed to the beginning of the file

    prec,chunk = '','go'
    base = [ '' for i in xrange(len(checking_list))]
    rows = []
    while chunk:
        chunk = f.read(110)
        ss = ''.join((prec,chunk))
        mat_dic = None
        for mat_dic in dicreg.finditer(ss):
            li = base[:]
            for mat_kv in kvregx.finditer(mat_dic.group()):
                k,v = mat_kv.group(2,5)
                li[posis[k]] = v
            rows.append(li)
        if mat_dic:
            prec = ss[mat_dic.end():]
        else:
            prec += chunk


    print '\n\n%s\n%s' % (checking_list,30*'___')
    print '\n'.join(str(li) for li in rows)
```

result

```
------------------------------------------------------------
ss   == '{surprise : "perturbating at start  ", game:Available Universal Dices Game,\n    player:FTROE875574,location\n:"Lakeview S'


------------------------------------------------------------
ss   == '{surprise : "perturbating at start  ", game:Available Universal Dices Game,\n    player:FTROE875574,location\n:"Lakeview School, Kingsmere Boulevard, Saskatoon, Saskatchewan , Canada",time:15h18}\n\n{"game":"Available","   player":"LOI4531",\n"l'

mmmmmmm dictionary found in ss mmmmmmmmmmmmmm
surprise  :  perturbating at start
game  :  Available Universal Dices Game
player  :  FTROE875574
location  :  "Lakeview School, Kingsmere Boulevard, Saskatoon, Saskatchewan , Canada"
time  :  15h18


------------------------------------------------------------
ss   == '\n\n{"game":"Available","   player":"LOI4531",\n"location":  "Perth, Australia","time":"08h13","date":"Available"}\n\n{"game":Available,player:PLLI874,location:"Chelsea, Lo'

mmmmmmm dictionary found in ss mmmmmmmmmmmmmm
game  :  Available
player  :  LOI4531
location  :  "Perth, Australia"
time  :  08h13
date  :  Available


------------------------------------------------------------
ss   == '\n\n{"game":Available,player:PLLI874,location:"Chelsea, London, England",time:20h35}\n\n{special:"midnight happening",game:"Available","player":YTR44,\n"location":"Paris, France","t'

mmmmmmm dictionary found in ss mmmmmmmmmmmmmm
game  :  Available
player  :  PLLI874
location  :  "Chelsea, London, England"
time  :  20h35


------------------------------------------------------------
ss   == '\n\n{special:"midnight happening",game:"Available","player":YTR44,\n"location":"Paris, France","time":"02h24"\n,\n"date":"Available"}\n\n{game:Available,surprise:"  hretyuuhuhu  ",player:FT875,location\n:,"time":11h22}\n\n{"'

mmmmmmm dictionary found in ss mmmmmmmmmmmmmm
special  :  midnight happening
game  :  Available
player  :  YTR44
location  :  "Paris, France"
time  :  02h24
date  :  Available

mmmmmmm dictionary found in ss mmmmmmmmmmmmmm
game  :  Available
surprise  :  hretyuuhuhu
player  :  FT875
location  :  
time  :  11h22


------------------------------------------------------------
ss   == '\n\n{"game":"Available","player":"LOI4531","location":\n"Damas,Syria","time":"unavailable","date":"Available"}\n\n{"surprise   " '

mmmmmmm dictionary found in ss mmmmmmmmmmmmmm
game  :  Available
player  :  LOI4531
location  :  "Damas,Syria"
time  :  unavailable
date  :  Available


------------------------------------------------------------
ss   == '\n\n{"surprise   " : GARAMANANATALA Tower ,  game:Available Dices,player  :\n  PuLuLu874,location:"  Westminster, London, England  ",time:20'


------------------------------------------------------------
ss   == '\n\n{"surprise   " : GARAMANANATALA Tower ,  game:Available Dices,player  :\n  PuLuLu874,location:"  Westminster, London, England  ",time:20h01}\n\n{"game":"Available",special:"overnight",   "player":YTR44,"location":\n"Madrid, Spain"    ,     "time":\n"12h33",\nda'

mmmmmmm dictionary found in ss mmmmmmmmmmmmmm
surprise  :  GARAMANANATALA Tower
game  :  Available Dices
player  :  PuLuLu874
location  :  "  Westminster, London, England  "
time  :  20h01


------------------------------------------------------------
ss   == '\n\n{"game":"Available",special:"overnight",   "player":YTR44,"location":\n"Madrid, Spain"    ,     "time":\n"12h33",\ndate:"Available"\n}'

mmmmmmm dictionary found in ss mmmmmmmmmmmmmm
game  :  Available
special  :  overnight
player  :  YTR44
location  :  "Madrid, Spain"
time  :  12h33
date  :  Available


------------------------------------------------------------
ss   == ''



checking_dict == {'player': 8, 'game': 8, 'location': 8, 'time': 8, 'date': 4, 'surprise': 3, 'special': 2}

checking_list        == ['surprise', 'game', 'player', 'location', 'time', 'date', 'special']

checking_list sorted == ['game', 'player', 'location', 'time', 'date', 'surprise', 'special']

posis == {'player': 1, 'game': 0, 'location': 2, 'time': 3, 'date': 4, 'surprise': 5, 'special': 6}


['game', 'player', 'location', 'time', 'date', 'surprise', 'special']
__________________________________________________________________________________________
['Available Universal Dices Game', 'FTROE875574', '"Lakeview School, Kingsmere Boulevard, Saskatoon, Saskatchewan , Canada"', '15h18', '', 'perturbating at start', '']
['Available', 'LOI4531', '"Perth, Australia"', '08h13', 'Available', '', '']
['Available', 'PLLI874', '"Chelsea, London, England"', '20h35', '', '', '']
['Available', 'YTR44', '"Paris, France"', '02h24', 'Available', '', 'midnight happening']
['Available', 'FT875', '', '11h22', '', 'hretyuuhuhu', '']
['Available', 'LOI4531', '"Damas,Syria"', 'unavailable', 'Available', '', '']
['Available Dices', 'PuLuLu874', '"  Westminster, London, England  "', '20h01', '', 'GARAMANANATALA Tower', '']
['Available', 'YTR44', '"Madrid, Spain"', '12h33', 'Available', '', 'overnight']
```

.

.

I wrote the above code thinking to an enormous file of several GB that couldn't be read entirely: the treatment of such a very big file must be done chunk after chunk. That's why there are instructions:

```
while chunk:
    chunk = f.read(120)
    ss = ''.join((prec,chunk))
    ecr.append('\n\n------------------------------------------------------------\nss   == %r' %ss)
    mat_dic = None
    for mat_dic in dicreg.finditer(ss):
        ............
        ...............
    if mat_dic:
        prec = ss[mat_dic.end():]
    else:
        prec += chunk
```

But, evidently, if the file isn't too big, hence readable in one shot, the code can be simplified:

```
import re

dicreg = re.compile('(?<=\{)[^}]*}')

kvregx = re.compile('[ \r\n]*'
                    '(" *)?((location)|[^:]+?)(?(1) *")'
                    '[ \r\n]*'
                    ':'
                    '[ \r\n]*'
                    '(?(3)|(" *)?)([^:]*?)(?(4) *")'
                    '[ \r\n]*(?:,(?=[^,]+?:)|\})')


checking_dict = {}
checking_list = []

filename = 'zzz.txt'

with open(filename) as f:
    content = f.read()




######## First part: to gather all the keys in all the dictionaries

ecr = []

for mat_dic in dicreg.finditer(content):
    ecr.append('\nmmmmmmm dictionary found in ss mmmmmmmmmmmmmm')
    for mat_kv in kvregx.finditer(mat_dic.group()):
        k,v = mat_kv.group(2,5)
        ecr.append('%s  :  %s' % (k,v))
        if k in checking_list:
            checking_dict[k] += 1
        else:
            checking_list.append(k)
            checking_dict[k] = 1


print '\n'.join(ecr)
print '\n\n\nchecking_dict == %s\n\nchecking_list        == %s' %(checking_dict,checking_list)

######## The keys are sorted in order that the less frequent ones are at the end
checking_list.sort(key=lambda k: checking_dict[k], reverse=True)
posis = dict((k,i) for i,k in enumerate(checking_list))
print '\nchecking_list sorted == %s\n\nposis == %s' % (checking_list,posis)



######## Now, the file is read again to build a list of rows 


base = [ '' for i in xrange(len(checking_list))]
rows = []

for mat_dic in dicreg.finditer(content):
    li = base[:]
    for mat_kv in kvregx.finditer(mat_dic.group()):
        k,v = mat_kv.group(2,5)
        li[posis[k]] = v
    rows.append(li)


print '\n\n%s\n%s' % (checking_list,30*'___')
print '\n'.join(str(li) for li in rows)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. After trying with a very big file, I got a memory error though : ecr.append('\n\n------------------------------------------------------------\nss   == %r' %ss)
MemoryError. I'll try to figure that out

Answer (score 1):

If it's more complicated then what you have given as examples, or if it has to be faster, you should probably look into [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/).

Otherwise you could write something more hacky like this:

```
contentlines = ["""{"game":"Available","player":"Available","location":"Chelsea, London, England","time":"Available","date":"Available"}""", """{game:Available,player:Available,location:"Chelsea, London, England",time:Available}"""]
def get_dict(line):
    keys = []
    values = []
    line = line.replace("{", "").replace("}", "")
    contlist = line.split(":")
    keys.append(contlist[0].strip('"').strip("'"))
    for entry in contlist[1:-1]:
        entry = entry.strip()
        if entry[0] == "'" or entry[0] == '"':
            endpos = entry[1:].find(entry[0]) + 2
        else:
            endpos = entry.find(",")
        values.append(entry[0:endpos].strip('"').strip("'"))
        keys.append(entry[endpos + 1:].strip('"').strip("'"))
    values.append(contlist[-1].strip('"').strip("'"))
    return dict(zip(keys, values))


for line in contentlines:
    print get_dict(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

text = """
{game:Available,player:Available,location:"Chelsea, London, England",time:Available}
{"game":"Available","player":"Available","location":"Chelsea, London, England","time":"Available","date":"Available"}
"""

dicts = re.findall(r"{.+?}", text)                         # Split the dicts
for dict_ in dicts:
    dict_ = dict(re.findall(r'(\w+|".*?"):(\w+|".*?")', dict_))    # Get the elements
    print dict_

>>>{'player': 'Available', 'game': 'Available', 'location': '"Chelsea, London, England"', 'time': 'Available'}
>>>{'"game"': '"Available"', '"time"': '"Available"', '"player"': '"Available"', '"date"': '"Available"', '"location"': '"Chelsea, London, England"'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this pyparsing solution is easier to follow and maintain over time:

```
data = """\
{game:Available,player:Available,location:"Chelsea, London, England",time:Available} 
{"game":"Available","player":"Available","location":"Chelsea, London, England","time":"Available","date":"Available"}"""

from pyparsing import Suppress, Word, alphas, alphanums, QuotedString, Group, Dict, delimitedList

LBRACE,RBRACE,COLON = map(Suppress, "{}:")
key = QuotedString('"') | Word(alphas) 
value =  QuotedString('"') | Word(alphanums+"_")
keyvalue = Group(key + COLON + value)

dictExpr = LBRACE + Dict(delimitedList(keyvalue)) + RBRACE

for d in dictExpr.searchString(data):
    print d.asDict()
```

Prints:

```
{'player': 'Available', 'game': 'Available', 'location': 'Chelsea, London, England', 'time': 'Available'}
{'date': 'Available', 'player': 'Available', 'game': 'Available', 'location': 'Chelsea, London, England', 'time': 'Available'}
```

Comment: Indeed! I used it to circumvent the memory issue with eyquem's answer. PyParsing seems very powerful

Comment: Edit: It's working well, but it is very slow at parsing, sadly. Thanks though